# Count same value on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have hive table like the following and I need to count occurrence of a team

```
team_name  opponent_team    match_won
csk        mm               mm
csk        dc               csk
mm         csk              csk
dc         csk              dc
```

Now I need data like:

```
team_name  total_matches    matches_won
csk        4                2
mm         2                1
dc         2                1
```

Can anybody help me with a query?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: hi Jens, since i'm new to sql i was not aware of case statements and was trying different combination with union all

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table to get all teams' games. `GROUP BY` that result. Use `case` expression to do conditional counting of won games:

```
select team_name,
       count(*) as total_matches,
       count(case when team_name = match_won then 1 end) as matches_won
from
(
    select team_name, match_won
    from gamestable
    union all
    select opponent_team, match_won
    from gamestable
) dt
group by team_name
```

`count(*)` counts all rows (within a group), while `count(case...)` counts only non-NULL values. (The `case` expression returns NULL if team_name is not equal to match_won.)

Comment: Hi Jarlh, query worked perfectly fine after adding alias to the sub query. Many thanks...